# Visual Studio query for linked server with a parameter

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

In the Visual Studio Designer - how can I setup the following query to have a dynamic where statement - ie. I want to pass in @dte:

```
SELECT 
CAST(inf.callrecord_callid as nvarchar(255)) as callrecord_callid
, inf.callrecord_contacttype
FROM OPENQUERY
(HPP_19,
' SELECT 
callrecord.callid as callrecord_callid, 
callrecord.contacttype as callrecord_contacttype

FROM    xdd:inform.callrecord callrecord  


WHERE callrecord.callstart >= MDY(MONTH(@dte),DAY(@dte),YEAR(@dte))
and callrecord.callstart < MDY(MONTH(@dte),DAY(@dte),YEAR(@dte)) + 1 UNITS Day'
) as inf
```

The designer advises: "An error occurred when creating the query"

It will let me save it, but then in my code, the GetData part, which should prompt for @dte - doesn't recognise that there is a parameter in the query.

My code is:

```
    Dim osc As New osccTableAdapters.osccTableAdapter
    Dim oscdata As oscc.osccDataTableDataTable
    oscdata = osc.GetData
```

The last line should allow me to type:

```
    oscdata = osc.GetData(dte)
```

So how can I pass @dte as a dynamic parameter, when VS won't compile because it doesn't think the query has a parameter?

thanks, Mark

Answer (score 0):

I've just found some other posts on this.

It's not possible to add a parameter to an OpenQuery in this way.  I'd have to use sprocs or some other workaround - but as far as the designed in VS goes, it's not possible.

Thanks anyway,
Mark